# Combining column values from different tables

Tags: oracle, union-all

I stuck. I have 2 tables - look at image no.1 [Table columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xprRX.jpg) And i would like to build query, that will give me the result - it is showed on image no 2. [the result of query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0W8D5.jpg).

I have 2 queries and I would like to mix them up, to obtain the list from image no.2. Please help me, how to build a query.

- Query no1: SELECT department_name, department_id FROM DEPARTMENTS WHERE department_id between 90 AND 110;
- Query no 2: SELECT last_name, department_id from employees WHERE department_id between 90 AND 110;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Query**:

```
with departments (department_id, department_name) as (
        select  90, 'Executive'  from dual union all
        select 100, 'Finance'    from dual union all
        select 110, 'Accounting' from dual
     ),
     employees (employee_id, last_name, department_id) as (
        select 1003, 'King'     ,  90 from dual union all
        select 1005, 'De Hann'  ,  90 from dual union all
        select 1009, 'Gietz'    , 110 from dual union all
        select 1013, 'Popp'     , 100 from dual union all
        select 1014, 'Chen'     , 100 from dual union all
        select 1015, 'Higgins'  , 110 from dual union all
        select 1029, 'Greenberg', 100 from dual union all
        select 1040, 'Kochar'   ,  90 from dual union all
        select 1043, 'Faviet'   , 100 from dual union all
        select 1045, 'Urman'    , 100 from dual union all
        select 1049, 'Sciarra'  , 100 from dual
     )
     --   end input data;   begin actual query   --
select c_name, department_id from 
  ( select department_name as c_name, department_id, 0 as categ from departments
    union all
    select '    ' || last_name as c_name, department_id, 1 from employees
    order by department_id, categ, c_name
  );
```

Result:

```
C_NAME        DEPARTMENT_ID
------------- -------------
Executive                90
    De Hann              90
    King                 90
    Kochar               90
Finance                 100
    Chen                100
    Faviet              100
    Greenberg           100
    Popp                100
    Sciarra             100
    Urman               100
Accounting              110
    Gietz               110
    Higgins             110
```

You don't need the "with ..." part; just use the query that begins at the SELECT statement after the two factored subqueries (after the "input data"). I even ordered by last name within each department for you; if that is not needed, just delete "c_name" from the ORDER BY clause.

I called the first column c_name; you may call it whatever you want, but calling it department_name when it also holds employee last names didn't make much sense to me. To call it whatever you want, change the SELECT statement from `SELECT c_name, department_id` to `SELECT c_name AS whatever, department_id...`

Comment: Great answer. I never used UNION, possibly the reason I wasn't aware of the usage. Thanks for a better answer.

Comment: Thank you  mathguy for you help. This answer is this what i asked.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.last_name,
       d.department_id,
       d.department_name
FROM employee c
JOIN deptartment d ON d.department_id=c.department_id
WHERE d.department_id BETWEEN 90 AN 110
```

**OUTPUT from my sample table**

```
+-------+----+------------+
| KING  | 10 | ACCOUNTING |
| BLAKE | 30 | SALES      |
| CLARK | 10 | ACCOUNTING |
| JONES | 20 | RESEARCH   |
| SCOTT | 20 | RESEARCH   |
+-------+----+------------+
```

Comment: Thanks, is there any posibility do list in a different way ?
DEPARTMENT_NAME ------DEPARTMENT_ID 
____________________________________________
And below LAST_NAME   list

Comment: Differently, how ?

Comment: @PirateX - of course you can, you just need to know how to do it. I will post the solution shortly.